# Проблема: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо из суммы всех работников вычислить среднее арифметическое.

```
sum_rob = int(input('Количество рабочих:'))

for sum_rob in range(1,sum_rob+1):
     info_rob = input('Введите ФИО рабочего:'), input('Должность рабочего:') # Введение ФИО рабочего и его должности
     sum_details = int(input('Количество сделанных деталей:')) # Ввод количества сделанных деталей рабочим
     price_1 = float(input('Цена детали за одну штуку:')) # Ввод цены детали за одну штуку

     pay_rob=float

     pay_rob = sum_details * price_1 # Ф-ла заработной платы рабочего

     print(', '.join(info_rob), pay_rob) # Вывод данных рабочего и его заработной платы

     sum_pay_rob = sum(pay_rob)

     mean_pay = sum_pay_rob / sum(sum_rob)
     print(mean_pay)
```

Например:
Количество рабочих: 2

Кол.сделанных деталей 10
Сумма детали 2.5
ЗП = 25

Кол.сделанных деталей 15
Сумма детали 3.1
ЗП = 46.5

Среднее арифметическое = 35.75

Comment: Приведите ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ фрагмент кода. Или вы считаете, что нам тут делать нечего, вводить вручную список ваших (к тому-же неизвестных нам) работников?

Comment: `sum(sum_rob)` — переменная `sum_rob` всё ещё имеет тип `float`, а функция суммирования не подходит для вещественных чисел. Вообще сам код выглядит на не оч: то `pay_rob=float` откуда-то, то в цикле Вы берёте `sum_rob` несчастную и проходите по ней и в интервале, и в итераторе...

Comment: `sum_pay_rob = sum(pay_rob)`— если `pay_rob` это просто число, то какой результат вы здесь ожидаете?

Comment: А вообще-то осень странная у вас программа. Вы вводите два числа : sum_details и price_1 перемножаете их между собой, получаете одно число  -  pay_rob, а потом требуете от интерпретатора просуммировать это одно число: sum_pay_rob = sum(pay_rob). Функция sum() по определению требует в качестве параметра итерируемый объект, а вы ему подсовываете единственное число. Исправляйте!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вопрос исправил на пример который должен выполняться. Заранее извиняюсь за код, я в этом новичок)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгой дискуссии и переработки вопроса имеем:

```
sum_rob = int(input('Количество рабочих:'))
sum_pay_rob=0
for sum_rob in range(1,sum_rob+1):
     info_rob = input('Введите ФИО рабочего:'), input('Должность рабочего:') # Введение ФИО рабочего и его должности
     sum_details = int(input('Количество сделанных деталей:')) # Ввод количества сделанных деталей рабочим
     price_1 = float(input('Цена детали за одну штуку:')) # Ввод цены детали за одну штуку
     pay_rob=float
     pay_rob = sum_details * price_1 # Ф-ла заработной платы рабочего
     print(', '.join(info_rob), pay_rob) # Вывод данных рабочего и его заработной платы
     sum_pay_rob = sum_pay_rob+pay_rob

mean_pay = sum_pay_rob / sum_rob
print(mean_pay)
```